# Work with BroadcastReceiver in many fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I working with a PDA that has a laser scanner. For that I'm working with `BroadcastReceiver` in many fragment. I have one activity that has a `BottomNavigationView` to switch between three fragments. I'm using `BroadcastReceiver` like this :

```
package com.example.package.fragments;


public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private final static String SCAN_ACTION = "scan.rcv.message";
    ScanDevice sm;


    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Doing my work
        }
    };

    public MyFragment () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MyFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CarteGriseFragment fragment = new CarteGriseFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        sm = new ScanDevice();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(SCAN_ACTION);
        getContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carte_grise, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sm = null;
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sm = null;
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
        sm = null;
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sm = null;
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        sm = null;
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

The problem is that, when I move to another fragment, `BroadcastReceiver` of the first fragment keep working in the second. In fact, when I scan something while being in the second fragment the `BroadcastReceiver` of the first fragment is called. I searched for many solutions, as you can see in the code above, I tried to unregister the `BroadcastReceiver`, but not working.

The code of the other fragment is similar to the code above.

Comment: best way is to put the broadcast receiver in parent activity which holds this three fragments. through interface you can communicate from activity to fragment viceversa

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in navigation view all fragments stays in a visible state, hence  onPause is not called. you can try to unsubscribe in this method `setUserVisibleHint`  when `isVisibleToUser = false`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use RxJava.

You say "**I have one activity**".

Use RxJava like this.

You need to just one **BroadcastReceiver** in your activity.Listen it when triggered "**onReceive**" function then you send event with RxJava and listen this event in your fragments.